# Print Bibliography Only

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I need to generate my references separately from the main document (i.e., one pdf with the content and one with the bibliography). I achieved this the following way:

To generate the pdf lacking references, compile the document with the following line `\nobibliography{bibfile}`. To compile, run `pdflatex`; `bibtex`; `pdflatex`; `pdflatex`.

To generate the pdf with only references, change the above line to `\bibliography{bibfile}`, and comment the entire document except this line and the `\bibliographystyle` line. To comment, I used **verbatim** (`\usepackage{verbatim}`) and enclosed everything within `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` with `\begin{comment}` and `\end{comment}`, except, as mentioned, the bibliography-pertinent commands. To compile, run `pdflatex` once.

Is there a simpler way to achieve the same result (one file with references only and one with content only)?

Comment: Could you tell more information about the way your bibliography is written (style used for instance). If it is only a author-year style, you could easily generate the bibliography file with a `nocite{*}` instruction before the `\printbibliography` command (syntax for `biblatex` use).

Comment: Hi Martigan. My bibliography style is `unsrt`, and references are numerically sorted by their order of appearance. Also, I am using `bibtex` (not `biblatex`).

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 4):

Maybe not exactly the solution to your problem, but I give it a shot: You could start the bibliography on a new page and reset the page counter to one

```
\newpage
\setcounter{page}{1}
\bibliography{bibfile}
```

This way you still produce one PDF file with both content and references, but you could separate them into two appropriately page numbered independent files.

Comment: Thanks vaettchen. That is a very useful suggestion. I could use a linux command line utility to split the document in two afterwards.

Comment: On linux, the splitting can be achieved with a combination of `pdfseparate` and `pdfsplit`.

Answer (score 3):

Lets assume `example.tex` is your document. In order to generate a document containing only the references used by `example.tex` you can proceed as follows:

Compile your document using `pdflatex`, then run `bibtex example` in order to generate the file `example.bbl` file. Now create a document `references.tex` containing something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  \input{example.bbl}
\end{document}
```

Finally compile the above document with `pdflatex`.